# C error: Exited with non-zero status

Tags: c

I know this code is quite simple; but that message won't stop appearing, can you help me find where the error is?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void Reverse(char * word[]) { 

  char temp = word[0];

  for (int i = sizeof(word); i >= 0; i--){
  for (int j = 0; j<= sizeof(word); j ++){

    word[0] = word[i];

  }


}

  word[sizeof(word)] = temp;

  printf("%s", word); 

}

void main() { 

  Reverse(gets(stdin));

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: `gets` is supposed to receive a buffer where string is supposed to be stored. `sizeof(word)` is wrong as well.

Comment: You need to make sure that your program compiles without warnings.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Your `main` function should have a return type of `int` because it has a `return` statement.

Comment: Use `strlen` with strings, not `sizeof` to determine the length.  As an experiment, print `sizeof(word)` and `strlen(word)` to see the difference.

Comment: Prefer to allocate an array of characters, then use `fgets` to read into the character array.  The `fgets` will allow you to limit the input to the size of the array.

Comment: Your argument to Reverse: `char * word[]` should be `char * word`. You have a pointer to `char`, not an array of `char` pointers. That's in addition to other comments already made about `sizeof`, etc.

Comment: There are just too many errors. No use to give an answer. Go back and read some more about C!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gets` returns `char*`. **In this context** - It is wrong to write `char *[]` in the function definition where you are supposedly passing a `char` array where input characters are being stored using `gets`. Also `char *gets(char *str)` - you need to pass a buffer to the `gets` where the inputted letters will be stored. You didn't pass one.

`sizeof` doesn't work here. It returns the size of a pointer (`char*`). You will have to use `strlen()` to get the length of the string inputted by `gets`.

More importantly - don't use `gets` - it's time to use something much safer than `gets`, namely `fgets` etc. Buffer overflow is not something you want to deal with.

Suppose you are passing an array of `char*` to the function `reverse`. Then the parameter would be `char*[]` which means nothing other than `char**` here. Here you will simply pass the `char` array which you will be using as buffer to `gets`.